# SpriteKit, how to create unlimited particles

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

This is what is on SpriteKit guide about SKEmitterNode particles:

**The numParticlesToEmit property specifies how many particles are created before the emitter turns itself off. You can also configure the node to emit an unlimited number of particles.**

Really? How?

I love these half cooked crappy docs Apple write.

Comment: check this out ,seems helpful http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Sprite_Kit_Particle_Emitter_Tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SKEmitterNode` emits unlimited particles if you set `numParticlesToEmit = 0`. This is also the default value. Any non-zero value will make the emitter stop generating particles after the specified number of them has been created.
You can read up on this in the [SKEmitterNode Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEmitterNode/numParticlesToEmit).

Comment: Does an analogous property also exist for an `SCNParticleSystem`? I can't seem to find any way to set the particles to be unlimited with SceneKit.